# use count in sql

Tags: sql

I need a SQL statement, the requirement is: there is a table, which has two columns: ID, Owner_ID; I inserted several records, for example:

```
ID    Owner_ID
0         0
1         0
2         1
3         1
4         2
5         3
6         3
7         3
8         3
9         0
```

Now I need a SQL statement, which returns a ID list sorted by the number of rows owned by different user, from largest to smallest. In this example, owner 3 has four rows; owner 0 has three rows, owner 1 has two rows; and owner 2 has one rows. the result should be

```
ID    Owner_ID
5         3
6         3
7         3
8         3
0         0
1         0
9         0
2         1
3         1
4         2
```

I think I should use the aggregate function count, does anybody have an idea?

I am using HSQLDB.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Which DBMS?  Generating the result in pure SQL as shown requires a DBMS that allows you to ORDER BY a (computed) column that is not present in the select-list, which is not standard SQL functionality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will work with most SQL DBMS, but shows the count value.

```
SELECT ID, Owner_ID, Owner_Count
  FROM AnonymousTable AS A
  JOIN (SELECT Owner_ID, COUNT(*) AS Owner_Count
          FROM AnonymousTable
         GROUP BY Owner_ID
       ) AS B ON B.Owner_ID = A.Owner_ID
 ORDER BY Owner_Count DESC, Owner_ID ASC, ID ASC;
```

This will work with some, but not necessarily all, DBMS; it orders by a column that is not shown in the result list:

```
SELECT ID, Owner_ID
  FROM AnonymousTable AS A
  JOIN (SELECT Owner_ID, COUNT(*) AS Owner_Count
          FROM AnonymousTable
         GROUP BY Owner_ID
       ) AS B ON B.Owner_ID = A.Owner_ID
 ORDER BY Owner_Count DESC, Owner_ID ASC, ID ASC;
```

Answer (score 4):

This is very straight-forward.

```
SELECT
  ID,
  Owner_ID
FROM
  TheTable t
ORDER BY
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TheTable i WHERE i.Owner_ID = t.Owner_ID) DESC
```

Comment: Or perhaps "ORDER BY (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TheTable i WHERE i.Owner_ID = t.Owner_ID) DESC, Owner_ID, ID"?

Comment: @Andy: If you want to. The OP did not specify any intra-group sorting, but that should be easy enough to figure out. :)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you have the general idea. Try the following query:

```
select t.ID, t.Owner_ID
from table t
inner join (select Owner_ID, count(*) c from table t group by Owner_ID) tc
  on t.Owner_ID = tc.Owner_ID
order by
  tc.c desc, t.ID asc
```